# How to map property names in POJO to field name .jrxml file?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using JasperReports library to generate reports from my Java classes. I'm wondering if there is a way to map property names in my Java classes to field name in the .jrxml report template file, instead of having to follow the exact field names in the .jrxml?
For example, I may have a Java class with a field "customerName", but in the .jrxml file I want the field to be called "customer_name" instead. Is there a way to specify this mapping, so I don't have to change my Java class field names?
Does there exist any annotation like @Field that can achieve this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I hope there is somehow a way to use annotion for mapping.

Answer (score 0):

There's no annotation to specify the report field name for a Java class property, but you can do that in the opposite direction.

To specify the Java class property name for a report field you can set [net.sf.jasperreports.javabean.field.property](https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.javabean.field.property) for the field:

```
<field name="customer_name" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.javabean.field.property" value="customerName"/>
</field>
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. However, my issue is that I need to map the property names in the Java class to the field names in the .jrxml report template file, instead of the other way around. I'm exploring other options, such as creating a custom data source or using a third-party library that supports this type of mapping.

Thank you for your help